# TFS: Best way to integrate a new code drop

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

Our project is based on another studio's technology, which we have modified to fit our needs.  We use TFS, they use Perforce.  They have just shipped their product and as a result, they have a lot of new finished features we want to pick up for our project.  I am tasked with integrating over this new code drop into our codebase.

I am very familiar with Perforce as I have been using it for years, but I am much less experienced with TFS (which is where all the work will take place) so I am pretty sure my approach will be brute force, tedious, and extremely time consuming.  Hopefully some of you will be able to suggest "the right way" to do this.  :)

Here's what I am doing:

1. Check out the entire project in TFS
2. Copy the entire new code drop over the old code
3. Merge all the changes we have made to their codebase into this new vanilla code drop (YIKES!)
4. Check in
5. Folder diff between the checked in codebase and the vanilla drop I sycned from Perforce and delete any files no longer in the project
6. Check in
7. Profit

As you can tell, this is going to be "fun".  I'm up to step 3 and I am realizing that I don't know how to actually do this merge in a way that doesn't require diffing every single friggin file in the project (approaching 3000).  I was hoping to get a window of all the conflicts I need to resolve like you do after syncing.

Furthermore, I just don't have confidence that this is going to work out well even if I did brute force diff every single file.  :)  Files moved, added, removed, etc are just going to be a nightmare.  Much of the work we want to pick up is refactoring their old messy early code from a much earlier state in the project when we last synced.

I have to believe that TFS can make this task much cleaner since what I am trying to do is not uncommon.  What would you guys suggest?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to have 2 branches in TFS, one that is the unmodified code from the other team (lets call this DEFAULT).  Then make a branch off that (lets call this CUSTOM).  You would make your changes in CUSTOM.

This way when the other team release new code you just Get Latest on DEFAULT, delete the local workspace files, copy over the new code, then let the local workspace feature do it's thing and detect all the necessary pending changes (adds, deletes, edits), then check-in the changes.  Then you can merge DEFAULT->CUSTOM and resolve any conflicts.

Since you don't have this structure setup now, setting it up the first time will be a little painful, but in the future it should make life easier.

Assuming you have a copy of the unmodified code from the previous release, you can create the DEFAULT branch and check that in.  Then branch off a CUSTOM branch.  Then Get Latest on CUSTOM, delete all the local workspace files, and copy in your current modified code.  VS should detect all the necessary pending changes, then check those in.

Now you can do the process to update DEFAULT, and merge down to CUSTOM for the new version.  Because TFS will track the history, you should only have to deal with actual conflicts rather than going through every single change.  You will of course have to do sufficient testing to ensure that the new code and your customizations still work well together.